# python pandas alter column from timestamp iso format to regular

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that some of the columns have dates in this format (iso format):

```
YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssTZD
```

I want to convert it to

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:SS[.SSSSSS]]
```

For example when I do:

```
print (df["create_date"])
```

I get:

```
2014-11-24 20:21:49-05:00
```

How can I alter the date in the column ?

Comment: What is expected output? Do you need `df['create_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['create_date'])` ?

Comment: @jezrael I want to replace the values in the df['create_date'] from iso format to the format I mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do this:

```
from datetime import datetime
df["new_date"] = df["create_date"].strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M[:%S[.%f]]")
```

If the column is type string, the try:

```
df["new_date"] = df["create_date"].dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M[:%S[.%f]]")
```

Then write this to csv/excel

```
import pandas as pd

df.to_csv("\\path\\file.csv")
```

Comment: but this won't replace the value in my dataframe. I'm exporting the dataframe to excel I need the values corrected there.

Comment: Updated as per your comment

Comment: Is there a reason why you assign to a new column? can't I replace the value?

Comment: Yes you can do it in the same column also

Comment: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'strftime'

Comment: So, can you check create_date column is string or datetime object ?